# WP7 and Facebook c# SDK Issue the allow button does not work

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I using the WP7 sample from the Facebook C# SDK (v5.2.1).  I click on on a button to log into FB and I am presented with a login screen.  Once I submit my credentials I am asked to add the device to facebook which I do.  I then am redirected to a permission page the has 2 buttons (allow and dont allow).  Nothing seems to happen if I click on either button.  Does anybody have any ideas on what the issue might be?

Thanks,

tom

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like an issue I was told about; this is casued due to a bug in facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/216725561726822

Try changing to display=wap

Comment: thanks for the tip. changing display to wap works fine for me! user996465 please mark this answer as the correct answer (checkmark on the left side)